# How can I get a random value from 0~600 with an interval of 10?

Tags: java, random

I have an 600x600 screen that I wanted to divide it each 10 squares basically so I can do an snake game, so I need to generate the food into those divisions.

The code I thought of:

```
x.nextInt(10)*x.nextInt(6)*x.nextInt(10)
```

This doesn't work, and even if it worked there are multiple values that can achieve 20, lets say 1*2*10, 2*1*10...

So I also thought of this:

```
(int)(x.nextInt(600)/10)*10
```

But it doesn't make the interval of 10...

I also thought of this one:

```
Integer.parseInt(Double.toString(x.nextInt(600)/10))*10
```

but its pretty much stupid and it doesn't work (gives an error)

if you didn't understood what I want, here is results:
Random pairs (x and y):
10, 60
420, 170
550, 480
80, 600

Here is what I don't want:
14, 52
88, 19
551, 529
415, 550

How can I manage the logic to make the random with this interval?

Comment: get random numbers from 0-60 and multiply by 10?

Comment: LoL, My logic level is negative, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try:

```
(int)(Math.random() * 60) * 10
```

Essentially this finds a random int between 0 and 59 then multiplies it by ten so that the numbers have a gap of 10...

Alternativly, you could take advantage of integer division and use

```
(int)(Math.random() * 600) / 10 * 10
```

which works on the same principle.

Comment: Although the OP states 60, he probably means 59.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by generating an integer between 0 and 60 (or I guess you really want 0 to 59 as a tile is 10 pixels wide and should be on the screen), and then multiplying that integer by 10.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Math.random()

```
 int random = (int )(Math.random() * 60 +1) * 10;
```

Description: 
random() method returns a random number between 0.0 and 0.999. So, you multiply it by 60, so upper limit becomes 0.0 to 59.999, when you add 1, it becomes 1.0 to 60.999, now when you you truncate to int, you get 1 to 60. and then multiply it by 10 to get a multiple of 10 between 10 to 600.

note: If you want from 0 to 60 remove 1 and use

```
 int random = (int )(Math.random() * 61) * 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a GridSquare class, with coordinates from 0 to 10 (randomly chosen), and then use a toScreenArea function that multiplies the coordinates by the number of pixels per square to find the appropriate spot on the screen to put the squares on.